# Three.js SSAO on a smooth mesh produces flat-shaded results

Tags: three.js, ssao

I am using Three.js r97 and in my scene I have a mesh using BufferGeometry with valid normals. When I am setting material.flatShading = false I see a smooth mesh, but when I apply SSAO postprocessing to this mesh (https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_ssao.html), I can see mesh triangles as if it's original material flatShading is set to true. Is there a parameter I am missing that can be set (on a depth material or in SSAO shader itself) to have SSAO not show original mesh triangles, but be smooth? depthMaterial used by SSAOPass has flatShading = false by default, but doesn't seem like it matters in this case.
Please see images below. Would be happy to provide more details if needed, as I have been stuck on this issue for several days now and at this point not even sure it can be done, other than making SSAO triangles less subtle by playing with radius, aoClamp and lumInfluence parameters.

Mesh - flat shading (material.flatShading = true):
[image]

Mesh - smooth shading (material.flatShading = false):
[image]

Mesh - smooth shading + SSAO:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for anyone that wonders about this - looks like SSAO in Three has been broken since r75:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8576